# How to parse something json-like with unquoted keys with aeson?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, haskell-req

I am trying to use `req` library to crawl a page. The response for the page, is *almost* a `JSON` object, except for the keys being unquoted.

Is it possible to use `Aeson` to do relaxed parsing of it?

What could be the simplest hack that I can do with `req` to do that.

I tried to do regex replace in bytestring to introduce quotes, but it gets enormously complicated soon.

Comment: Is filing a bug report to get a valid JSON response an option?

Comment: It may be easier to write your own parser. Perhaps take a copy of the Aeson parser and make the changes to it -- you now have something you can work with.

Comment: You might be able to pre-process the response with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/); treat the response as a filter: `bad_json='{foo: "bar"}'; jq -n "$bad_json"` will output `{"foo": "bar"}`.

Comment: @chepner I don't think its possible. Its not even a documented API. I think writing my own parser is the only way to go about this I think.

Comment: There might be value in having a permissive parsing mode in `aeson` that handled various types of malformed input. So if you extended `aeson` it might result in a patch that could be upstreamed